# Do these bicycle tubes fit my tires?

Tags: tire, innertube

I have an old race bicycle and the front wheel got flat (hole somewhere)

it has the following tires:

28 / 32 - 630 (27 X 1 1/4) HS 159

I bought twice of [these](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B015OREOBE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1):

2 x Schwalbe Marathon GreenGuard Draht Reflex Reifen 27 x 1 1/4 | 32-630

And also a pair of [these](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B000AQQVF2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1):

Schlauch Schwalbe SV 15, 27/28x3/4-1 1/8" 18/28-622/630, SV40mm

Looking carefully on the package, it doesn't list 28-630..  the closest is 28-622 or 25-630..

I'd like to know if the tubes are suitable for the tires, because they looks something shorter:

[image]

Comment: as long as the ISO (630) matches you should be good, the other number is the width size. Don't try and use a tube listed as 25 x 622 though as it is too small. You want the ISO to match. 622 is the ISO for a 29er or 700C tire 27" wheels are actually marginally bigger that a 29er. crazy i know. On a personal level i also find the way Schwalbe lists sizings confusing but thats the american in me lol

Comment: Either one will work.  A 27-inch tube is a 27-inch tube, so long as the width isn't too far off.  But the second tube you have is a little small, width-wise.  It would likely work but would be a bit more stressed -- I wouldn't hesitate to use it if it's all you have, but if you have a choice use the wider tube.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll return them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tubes are quite forgiving, you should get away with it without much trouble.  I've seen a 24" tube survive on a 26" wheel.

Don't worry about the *listed* sizes, you've got an unusual wheel diameter and can't necessarily expect all tyres widths to make it onto the list. But the tube will be quite stretched (1 1/8 being smaller than 1 1/4 or 28<32) so you may be marginally more likely to get a puncture than you would with a tube of the right cross section.  Probably not enough that you'd notice on the tyres you've bought though.  You might have to fiddle about a bit mounting the tube and tyre, perhaps inflating it into the tyre to get everything on the rim without pinching the tube.